# Как добавить зависимость в Swift Package Manager только для iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Есть ios проект с включенным Catalyst.
У проекта есть зависимость YandexMobileMetrica которая не умеет компилироваться для mac архитектуры.
Как с помощью Swift Package Manager добавить зависимость только для iOS?

Я попробовал сделать два таргета. В первом spm-test я отключил флаг Mac. А во втором spm-test-mac оставил. Мой Package.swift выглядит так:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "spm-test",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "spm-test",
            targets: ["spm-test"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "YandexMobileMetrica", url: "https://github.com/yandexmobile/metrica-sdk-ios", from: "3.14.1"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "spm-test",
            dependencies: ["YandexMobileMetrica"]),
        .target(
            name: "spm-test-mac",
            dependencies: [])
    ]
)
```

swift build не выдает ошибок. Но при этом при компиляции таргета spm-test я получаю ошибку:

```
AppDelegate.swift:11:12: No such module 'YandexMobileMetrica'
```

---

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//

import UIKit

#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    import YandexMobileMetrica
    import GoogleMobileAds
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы говорите про [SupportedPlatform](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/efbc4edf90faae7fc5c666afc15eb515322e07bb/Documentation/PackageDescription.md#supportedplatform), который вы можете передать в ините

```
Package(
    name: "spm-test",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v10)],
    ...
```